# Filling Grid (Vaadin) with Data

Tags: java, grid, vaadin

Hello Stackoverflow Community,

I've got a question for the Vaadin Grid. 
For example: I create a Class (Food) where I've got normal setter and getter methods for the name, price, and an ID.

Now I'm creating in the MyUI class from Vaadin a new Grid, I would like to create different kind of foods and add them to the grid.

When I'm trying to do it like this: 
List food = Arrays.asList(
 pseudo code new Food ()...
);

I can only set the ID. But how can I fill the grid with all three data variables? I also tried to add them by row ( had the topline with Name, Price, ID) but then he didn't add the data.

The documentation from Vaadaa is not really helpful.

Any experience?

Best Regards

Comment: Simplest is to create the 3 instances and add them to a `LinkedList`you then assign this list to the grid via setItems  https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/java-examples

Comment: Can you provide us a minimal and functional code snipped to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
    Grid<Food> grid = new Grid<>(Food.class);
    grid.setItems(listOfFoods);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the list of foods to the constructor of the Grid. `Grid<Food> grid = new Grid<Food>(food);` where food is the list that you had in your own code example.

Comment: Hello Jens, thanks for your quick answer. 
If I do so, I'm getting the following Error: 

      essenList = new ArrayList<>();

        Essen essen = new Essen(1);
        essen.setEssenName("Pfannkuchen");
        essen.setEssenPreis(3.5);
        essenList.add(essen);
        
        Grid<Essen> grid = new Grid<Essen>(essenList);
        
        layout.addComponents(grid);
        setContent(layout);

Cannot resolve constructor 'Grid(java.util.List<strucutre.Essen>)'

Comment: Maybe I remembered the API wrong. Try to do like Tulio suggested. Instead of `Grid<Essen> grid = new Grid<Essen>(essenList); ` do this: `Grid<Essen> grid = new Grid<Essen>(); grid.setItems(essenList);`